# Running spark-submit from a machine not in a Hadoop cluster

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I am trying to set up a Spark client distribution for our analysts they can use from their desktops.

To achieve this, I added a "pre-built with user-provided Apache Hadoop" version of Spark to my existing Hadoop client distribution. I've tried this both on Windows (the clients are deployed in `C:\HadoopClient`) and on Linux (the clients are deployed in `~`)

I am trying to launch the most basic `spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.examples.SparkPi --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster Spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.12-3.1.1.jar` and it fails with `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/fs/FSDataInputStream`

I've checked the usual suspects:

- JAVA_HOME, HADOOP_HOME, SPARK_HOME, HADOOP_CONF_DIR, SPARK_CONF_DIR and PATH are all set correctly
- SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH contains the contents of `hadoop classpath`

I've checked `launch_container.sh` on the Hadoop cluster and I've noticed that the CLASSPATH variable looks like this:

`$PWD:$PWD/__spark_conf__:$PWD/__spark_libs__/*:/etc/hadoop/conf/*:/usr/lib/hadoop/*:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/*:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/*:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/*:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/*:/etc/hadoop/conf/*:/usr/lib/hadoop/*:/usr/lib/hadoop/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/*:/usr/lib/hadoop-hdfs/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/*:/usr/lib/hadoop-yarn/lib/*:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/*:/usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce/lib/*:` followed by the entire contents of my SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH variable from the standalone machine (either `C:\HadoopClient\Hadoop\share...` or `/home/user/Hadoop/share...`).

`org/apache/hadoop/fs/FSDataInputStream` is from `hadoop-common-3.1.2.jar`, which should be on the CLASSPATH, as it's located in `/usr/lib/hadoop` on the cluster nodes. I actually looked inside just in case, and `FSDataInputStream.class` is there in the right place.

1. **Why can't Yarn find `hadoop-common-3.1.2.jar` if it's on the classpath?**
2. **What is my SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH doing in the classpath of the Yarn job? Is it harmless waste, or am I doing something wrong?**

When I use a different distribution of Spark, the one that is pre-built for Apache Hadoop 3.1.2 (our Hadoop version), the job crashes even quicker, with

```
Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/hadoop/conf/Configuration
```

And the CLASSPATH variable looks like this:

`$PWD:$PWD/__spark_conf__:$PWD/__spark_libs__/*:` followed by the entire contents of my SPARK_DIST_CLASSPATH variable from the standalone machine.

In this case I can agree that there's no `hadoop-common-3.1.2.jar` on the classpath. The `%SPARK_HOME%\jars` directory on the standalone machine definitely contains `hadoop-common-3.1.2.jar`, but it's not present in `$PWD/__spark_libs__/` on the cluster.

3. **Why isn't spark-submit sending the jar to the Hadoop cluster?**

Comment: Your standalone machine doesn't matter if you're using cluster deploy mode. That being said, your YARN CLASSPATH variable repeats many entries more than once, by the way, but look for the necessary JAR in those folders

Comment: Also, have you created any config entry for `spark.yarn.archives`?

Comment: @OneCricketeer I didn't, but cluster admins did. Turns out that was the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the problem was in spark-defaults.conf that I had in SPARK_CONF_DIR. I copied the whole `conf` directory from the cluster node to access Hive, but spark-defaults.conf was tuned to be run from the cluster node and overrode `spark.yarn.archives`. I removed the file from the configuration and was able to submit the job to the Yarn cluster successfully.